# Extracting joined image collection data from Earth Engine as a CSV

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, export, csv

### Setting the context

1. Prepare region of interest as multiple sites together as a `FeatureCollection`

```
var roi_list = [ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(146.007,-17.653), {name: 'S1'}),
                ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(146.061,-17.444), {name: 'S1'}),
                ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(145.960,-17.789), {name: 'S3'}),
                ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(151.937,-24.338), {name: 'S4'})]

var roi = ee.FeatureCollection(roi_list);
```

2. Generate a time series for several datasets where data is aggregated by month.

```
// Soil Moisture
var smap_mnth = ee.List.sequence(0, 5*12).map(function(n) { // .sequence: number of years from starting year to present
  var start = ee.Date('2016-01-01').advance(n, 'month') // Starting date
  var end = start.advance(1, 'month'); // Step by each iteration
  return ee.ImageCollection('NASA_USDA/HSL/SMAP_soil_moisture')
        .filterBounds(roi)
        .filterDate(start, end)
        .mean()
        .set('system:time_start', start.millis())
})

// Drought index
var kbdi_mnth = ee.List.sequence(0, 5*12).map(function(n) { // .sequence: number of years from starting year to present
  var start = ee.Date('2016-01-01').advance(n, 'month') // Starting date
  var end = start.advance(1, 'month') // Step by each iteration
  return ee.ImageCollection('UTOKYO/WTLAB/KBDI/v1')
        .filterBounds(roi)
        .filterDate(start, end)
        .mean()
        .set('system:time_start', start.millis())
})

// TRMM Precipitation
var trmm_mnth = ee.List.sequence(0, 5*12).map(function(n) { // .sequence: number of years from starting year to present
  var start = ee.Date('2016-01-01').advance(n, 'month') // Starting date
  var end = start.advance(1, 'month'); // Step by each iteration
  return ee.ImageCollection('TRMM/3B43V7')
        .filterBounds(roi)
        .filterDate(start, end)
        .mean()
        .set('system:time_start', start.millis())
})

// GPM Precipitation
var gpm_mnth = ee.List.sequence(0, 5*12).map(function(n) { // .sequence: number of years from starting year to present
  var start = ee.Date('2016-01-01').advance(n, 'month') // Starting date
  var end = start.advance(1, 'month') // Step by each iteration
  return ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_V05')
        .filterBounds(roi)
        .filterDate(start, end)
        .mean()
        .set('system:time_start', start.millis())
})

// Evapotranspiration
var et_mnth = ee.List.sequence(0, 5*12).map(function(n) { // .sequence: number of years from starting year to present
  var start = ee.Date('2016-01-01').advance(n, 'month') // Starting date
  var end = start.advance(1, 'month') // Step by each iteration
  return ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD16A2')
        .filterBounds(roi)
        .filterDate(start, end)
        .mean()
        .set('system:time_start', start.millis())
})
```

3. Each of the aggregations outputs a `list` which I then convert to an `ImageCollection`.

```
var smap_collection = ee.ImageCollection(smap_mnth)
var kbdi_collection = ee.ImageCollection(kbdi_mnth)
var trmm_collection = ee.ImageCollection(trmm_mnth)
var gpm_collection = ee.ImageCollection(gpm_mnth)
var et_collection = ee.ImageCollection(et_mnth)
```

4. ... and then `print` to the console

```
print(smap_collection)
print(kbdi_collection)
print(trmm_collection)
print(gpm_collection)
print(et_collection)
```

*At this point, I am able to plot the time series data as a chart in earth engine and can see the data points. Suffice to say, the code seems to work up until this point.*

### My Problem

---

What follows is my attempt to combine the datasets into one and then write them out to a .csv format.

---

I found information at this [link](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/joins_inner), suggesting I should use an inner join to combine `ImageCollections`.

*I considered resampling, but as my `geometry` consists only of points, I decided it was not necessary (but accept that this may have been poor judgement).*

1. So first I set up the join

```
// Merge on date column in all dataets
var filter = ee.Filter.equals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
});

// Create the join
var simpleJoin = ee.Join.inner();
```

2. Then I joined two datasets as a pair, then subsequently added to this pair. This seemed like the obvious move, as I couldn't find a way to join multiple at once.

```
// Inner join KBDI and soil moisture
var ks_innerJoin = ee.ImageCollection(simpleJoin.apply(kbdi_collection, smap_collection, filter))
var ks_joined = ks_innerJoin.map(function(feature) {
  return ee.Image.cat(feature.get('primary'), feature.get('secondary'));
})

// Inner join KBDI, soil moisture, and rainfall (TRMM)
var kst_innerJoin = ee.ImageCollection(simpleJoin.apply(ks_joined, trmm_collection, filter))
var kst_joined = kst_innerJoin.map(function(feature) {
  return ee.Image.cat(feature.get('primary'), feature.get('secondary'));
})

// Inner join KBDI, soil moisture, rainfall (TRMM), and rainfall (GPM)
var kstg_innerJoin = ee.ImageCollection(simpleJoin.apply(kst_joined, gpm_collection, filter))
var kstg_joined = kstg_innerJoin.map(function(feature) {
  return ee.Image.cat(feature.get('primary'), feature.get('secondary'));
})

// Inner join KBDI, soil moisture, rainfall (TRMM), rainfall (GPM), and evapotranspiration
var kstge_innerJoin = ee.ImageCollection(simpleJoin.apply(kstg_joined, et_collection, filter))
var kstge_joined = kstge_innerJoin.map(function(feature) {
  return ee.Image.cat(feature.get('primary'), feature.get('secondary'));
})
```

3. This was then printed to the console

```
// Print final dataset to console
print(kstge_joined)
```

4. Now for the exporting of the data. When I export this with `fileFormat: 'CSV'` I cannot see any data in the csv file.

```
// Export data to google drive
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: kstge_joined,
  description: 'WaterBalanaceFireData',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

The output looks as follows:
[image: This is how the output appears]